On Linux, how can I check whether an open serial port is still actually connected?
I have a serial device connected via USB. I've opened the tty (/dev/ttyACM0) and wait for incoming messages which are read and processed, then I wait for the next message. The problem is if the usb device gets disconnected, my code does not detect this and essentially hangs.
One solution would be to check the return value of the read() function, if it's 0 then use system("lsof ...") to check whether it's still connected. This would work but it feels pretty clumsy to me. Is there a better way to detect device disconnection in c code?

Update the protocol to regularly send a "ping" message, that your program sends and then expects a reply within a specific time-frame. If there's no reply, the device is gone.

"On error, -1 is returned, and errno  is  set  appropriately." -- as per man page. One thing I would look at is libusb (for more specific USB support) and perhaps inotify for general filesystem events. Point is, you're not looking for a serial port disconnect (which may not even be detectable, depending on the connected wires) but a USB disconnect.

@Ulrich - yes you're right, I cant detect serial disconnects so I need to look for USB disconnects. I'm thinking udev ...

If read() returns 0, it's disconnected. No need to check anything.

Read() does sometimes return 0 when the device is connected and working normally.

You should be able to poll for a POLLHUP event.

^ By which I mean poll the open tty file descriptor and check for the POLLHUP flag in the struct pollfd revents member. You may wish to also check for the POLLERR flag.

Thanks to all those that responded.
I found several solutions to this: using stat()/fstat() as described here 1. stat() will return -1 with errno==ENOENT, and fstat() will return stat.st_nlink=0 when the usb device is unplugged.
However, I think I'll go with the poll() solution suggested by @IanAbbott. It feels a little more tightly coupled to what I want to do, though all the above solutions worked.
